# How can I copy a whole html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Let's say I have some elements like:

```
<div id="some-id" class="some-class">
   <h1>Something here</h1>
</div>
```

And I would like to copy the whole **some-id** element together with all it's children, send it to database and then, when reloading the page, append them to the body.

I tried:

- clone() and I got: "prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[0], context: undefined, constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…"
- cloning and JSON.stringify() and I got one warning and one error in the console:

'Attr.ownerElement' is deprecated and has been removed from DOM4 (http://w3.org/tr/dom). 
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

What can I use to end up with the html structure of my element that I can put in the database and re-use it?

Comment: you have to get the html for the element like `$('#some-id')[0].outerHTML`

Comment: Yes sir! Works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to persist a html structure, then you need to use its html string, you can't stringify the dom reference. The html string can be saved and can be used later to append back to the dom.

```
var string = $('#some-id')[0].outerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `outerHTML` :

```
document.getElementById('some-id').outerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery clone should do the job. Try this:

```
var elem = $('#some-id');
var clone = elem.clone();
```

Besides, why are you saving it to the DB?